# Getting data from a Java applet

Tags: java, sql-server, database, applet

I have created a Java applet which will be embedded on a website. Clients will run the applet (which is a game) on the website, and necessary data will be taken.

I need to receive this data somehow so I can analyze it. There will be many clients though and lots of said data will need to be received.

**How can I do that?**

I have read online about using a database through MySQL or SQLite. However, these seem very complicated and I don't know how to work with them. Should I use either of these database services? If so, how would I set them up to work with the applet???

Comment: You need to have some software on the server-side to receive and process data. What do you prefer? Java, PHP, Rails, Python? Then your applet has to send HTTP requests that contain the data.

Comment: Do I actually need software on the server-side? Couldn't I also just send an HTTP POST request to upload data to a webpage and retrieve whatever is on that webpage to retrieve the data?

Comment: Basically, yes, you need software on the server-side. If you only want to do what you described -- storing and fetching HTTP POST requests, that's very easy to do with a 10-20 line PHP script; even if you use a database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a regular applet (and not JNLP), the security sandbox will prevent the applet from communicating with anything other than the webserver from which it was downloaded. So whatever webserver hosts the applet needs to also have some means of accepting and persisting/broadcasting HTTP GETS, POSTS, etc from the Applet.

Comment: A 'regular' applet and app. launched using JWS use the same security environment.